# Proving statement $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$ converges iff $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(1 + \frac{1}{n})a_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it true that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n$ converges $\iff$ $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(1 + \frac{1}{n})a_n$ converges? 
I think that I can prove the $\implies$ implication:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(1 + \frac{1}{n})a_n = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(a_n+\frac{a_n}{n})$$
We know that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a_n}{n}$ converges from Dirichlet's test so the sum of these two series is finite so the series above converges. 
I don't have any idea how to prove <= implication. Any hints?

Comment: do you know whether $a_n$ is positive?

Comment: Are you sure that $\sum_n(a_n)+\sum_n(\frac{a_n}{n})=\sum_n(a_n+\frac{a_n}{n})$?

Comment: @alonkol $a_n$ can be any sequence

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I've used arithmetic properties of limits

Comment: What if $\sum a_n$ convergent, $\epsilon_n \to 0$ but not decreasing, does it imply $\sum (1+\epsilon_n) a_n$ convergent ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dirichlet's test, as you know, says that if $f(n)$ is a decreasing positive function, and $\sum a_n$ converges (or even just boundedly oscillates), then $\sum f(n)a_n$ converges. Assuming that $\sum a_n$ converges, you applied this with $f(n)=1/n$ to show that $\sum a_n/n$ converges; your implication then follows from $\sum a_n + \sum a_n/n = \sum (1+1/n)a_n$.

Conversely, assume that $\sum (1+1/n)a_n$ converges. Define $f(n)=1/(n+1)$; then $\sum f(n)(1+1/n)a_n = \sum a_n/n$ converges by Dirichlet's test again. The converse implication then follows from $\sum (1+1/n)a_n - \sum a_n/n = \sum a_n$.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted $\sum_n f(n) (1+1/n) a_n = \sum_n a_n/n$?

Comment: Good catch - fixed!